# Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'String?'

Tags: swift, password-generator

new to programming and not quite grasping how this is wrong, any advice is appreciated.

```
func exercise() {
    let alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

    var char0 = alphabet.randomElement()
    var char1 = alphabet.randomElement()
    var char2 = alphabet.randomElement()
    var char3 = alphabet.randomElement()
    var char4 = alphabet.randomElement()
    var char5 = alphabet.randomElement()

    print(char0 + char1 + char2 + char3 + char4 + char5)
}
```

Comment: Hint : ```randomElement()``` will give you optional value / nil value. Is it possible to use + with nil ??????

Comment: The reason why randomElement can't always give you a value, and sometimes would give you nil, is because the array may be empty, if you wrote let alphabet: [String] = [], then there are no elements, so alphabet.randomElement could not be a particular string, so in general, randomElement has to return an optional string, aka String? and you have to handle that possibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have explained why your code gives an error. (`String.randomElement()` returns an `Optional<String>`, which is not the same thing as a String, and you can't use + to concatenate Optionals.)

Another point: Your code is verbose and repetitive. There is a principle, "DRY", in computer science. It stands for "Don't Repeat Yourself". Any time where you have the same code over and over (maybe with slight variations) it is "code smell", and an opportunity to improve.

You could rewrite your code without repetition like this:

```
func exercise() {
    let alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

   var result = ""
   for _ in 1...6 {
     result.append(alphabet.randomElement() ?? "")
   }
   print(result)
}
```

In that version, the expression `alphabet.randomElement()` only appears once. You don't repeat yourself. It also uses the `??` "nil coalescing operator" to convert possibly nil results to blank strings.

---

Another way to handle it would be to define an override of the `+=` operator that lets you append String optionals to a string:

```
public func +=(left: inout String, right: Optional<String>) {
    left = left + (right ?? "")
}
```

Then your function becomes:

```
func exercise() {
    let alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
   var result = ""
   for _ in 1...6 {
    result += alphabet.randomElement()
   }
   print(result)
}
```

---

Yet another way would be to shuffle your source array, fetch the first 6 elements, and then join them back together into a String:

```
func exercise() {
    let alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
    
    let result = alphabet
        .shuffled()[1...6]
        .joined()
    print(result)
}
```

Comment: Personally, I think the `+` and `+=` operators should be defined for appending all combinations of `String` and `String<Optional>` types. That would make this sort of thing much less fussy.

Answer (score 2):

The important part of the error message to understand is that String and String? (optional) are considered to be 2 different types by the compiler.

For some cases the compiler can make a (implicit) conversion so the types are the same but not here since it can't convert nil and the + operator only works for two variables/literal values of the same type.

Consider this case

```
var char0 = alphabet.randomElement()
var char1 = alphabet.randomElement() ?? ""
```

If we now do `print("0: \(char0) 1: \(char1)")` the result is quite different for the 2 variables

> 0: Optional("p") 1: d

which we also see if we examin their types using `print("0: \(type(of: char0)) 1: \(type(of: char1))")`

> 0: Optional<String> 1: String

Comment: What does doing .self do, vs not using it?

Comment: @aheze Actually nothing, I was playing around with some different code and forgot to remove them. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

Give default value to variables by using ?? operator in case of nil. It will change type of variables from String? to String

```
func exercise() {

    let alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

    var char0 = alphabet.randomElement() ?? ""
    var char1 = alphabet.randomElement() ?? ""
    var char2 = alphabet.randomElement() ?? ""
    var char3 = alphabet.randomElement() ?? ""
    var char4 = alphabet.randomElement() ?? ""
    var char5 = alphabet.randomElement() ?? ""

    print(char0 + char1 + char2 + char3 + char4 + char5)
}
```

Comment: Just simple : ```print([char0, char1, char2, char3, char4, char5].reduce(""){$0 + ($1 ?? "")})```